# separate characters from string in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
10000001 - ppppppp pppppp - ffffffff ffff - jjjj
```

i need to get:

```
ffffffff ffff as 'column1'
jjjj  as 'column2'
```

lengths of characters after 2nd and 3rd '-' hyphen can vary.

I tried the following code- it works but it doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing it esp because I am using +18 and I am worried the character lengths may vary.

```
select case_id, 
LEFT(status_place,CHARINDEX('-',status_place)) numberID, 
SUBSTRING(status_place,CHARINDEX('-',status_place)+1,LEN(status_place)) todel,
SUBSTRING(status_place,CHARINDEX('-',status_place)+18,LEN(status_place)) Together
into #Prefinal
from [DD_PLACES]

select *,
LEFT(together,CHARINDEX('-',together)) Agency,
right(together, len(together) - charindex('-', together)) as 'Program'
into #final
from #Prefinal
select C_id, Agency, Program 
from #final
drop table #prefinal
drop table #final
```

Answer (score 2):

ParseName would be a good fit here

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,status_place varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'10000001 - ppppppp pppppp - ffffffff ffff - jjjj')

Select ID
      ,column1 = PARSENAME(replace(status_place,' - ','.'),2)
      ,column2 = PARSENAME(replace(status_place,' - ','.'),1)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  column1         column2
1   ffffffff ffff   jjjj
```

> **EDIT - Allowing for more dashes**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,status_place varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'10000001 - ppppppp pppppp - ffffffff ffff - jjjj')
,(2,'100000001 - Prrrrrrr Record - Viiiiiii Niiii Seeeeee Of Nnn Yyyy - Vvvvv - Mannnnnnn AAA')

Select ID
      ,column1 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(status_place,' - ','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
      ,column2 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(status_place,' - ','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
ID  column1                             column2
1   ffffffff ffff                       jjjj
2   Viiiiiii Niiii Seeeeee Of Nnn Yyyy  Vvvvv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John. It worked for some cases but not for all like:     
100000001 - Prrrrrrr Record - Viiiiiii Niiii Seeeeee Of Nnn Yyyy - Vvvvv -  Mannnnnnn AAA . the result should be : Viiiiiii Niiii Seeeeee Of Nnn Yyyy as column 1,  Vvvvv -  Mannnnnnn AAA as column 2

Comment: @PD_Taha Are you always looking for the last two values ?

Comment: @PD_Taha See EDIT which uses an XML Approach

Comment: Not the last two values BUT first column should be anything after 2nd '-'  and column2 should be anything after 3rd '-' hyphen.

Comment: @PD_Taha Updated the edit.  Removed the reverse portion.

Answer (score 0):

To me your approach is close to the result, because CHARINDEX is fast in SQL queries. So I would keep your initial approach, and focus on resolving your concern: the fact that you don't want to hard code the position of the hyphens because they are not fixed.

You do this by using the third option of the CHARINDEX function, which indicates from which point to start seraching. And since you are interested in the right side of the text string, I would suggest to use REVERSE to put the end at the start. Then REVERSE again to put the result in the right order. You can copy the whole code below and run it in SQL server.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (status_place VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @table (status_place) VALUES ('10000001 - ppppppp pppppp - ffffffff ffff - jjjj')
INSERT INTO @table (status_place) VALUES ('10000001 - ppppppp ppppp - ffffffff ff - jjjj')
INSERT INTO @table (status_place) VALUES ('10000001 - ppppppp pppp - ffffffff ffff - jjjj')
INSERT INTO @table (status_place) VALUES ('10000001 - ppppppp ppppppp - ffffffffff ffff - jjjj')
INSERT INTO @table (status_place) VALUES ('10000001 - ppppppp pppppppppp - fffffffffffff ffff - jjjj')
INSERT INTO @table (status_place) VALUES ('10000001 - ppppppp pppp - ffff ffff - jjjj')

UPDATE @table SET status_place = (LTRIM(RTRIM(status_place)))

SELECT 
    status_place,
    REVERSE (status_place) AS reverse_status_place, 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(
    REVERSE ( 
        SUBSTRING   (
            REVERSE(status_place),
            0,
            CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(status_place),0)
                    ) 
            ) 
    )) AS column1,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(
    REVERSE (
        SUBSTRING   
        (
            REVERSE(status_place),
            CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(status_place),0)+1,
            (   
                (   CHARINDEX   (
                        '-',
                        REVERSE(status_place),
                        CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(status_place),0)+1
                                )
                )
                -
                (   CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(status_place),0)+1    )
            )
        ) 
    )
    )) AS column2
FROM @table
```

Quick explanation of my code: first I create a memory table and I load several possibilities with different positions for the hyphens. I then remove the leading and training spaces using LTRIM and RTRIM. This is a standard good practice (except if you want to keep these spaces) because we will count the characters and spaces can create noise because some SQL built in functions count them, others don't. So get rid of the unnecessary spaces.

Then I do a select of the status_place and a REVERSE of it, just to help debugging.
The next part looks complicated but it is not:

First the column1: it is a SUBSTRING of the REVERSE(status_place), which is then REVERSED again. This substring has 3 parameters: column name, starting point and length. Starting point is 0, length is the CHARINDEX of the first hyphen (first because we have reversed the text).

Then the second column, a little bit tricky: it is another substring of the REVERSE of the column, but it starts from the position of the first hyphen +1 and has a lengths if the distance between the first and the second hyphen.

The distance between the first and the second hyphen is the position of the second hyphen minus the position of the first hyphen. We already have the position of the first hyphen, so we need to get the position second hyphen.

The position second hyphen is obtained by using the third parameter of the CHARINDEX function: the starting point. As a starting point, we use the position of the first hypen +1, then CHARINDEX starts searching for the next hyphen after the first hyphen which is... the second hyphen. 
And we have the length of the SUBSTRING.

Each is then REVERSED again, and I use LTRIM and RTRIM to clean up leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation Jerome.